# Search for text inside java command output

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, text-processing

I have a folder which have multiple Jar files.
    * dummy.jar
    * myjar-xx.jar
    * myjar-yy.jar

Using find, I need to find first file starting with "myjar"

Now, I want to grep the contents of the Manifest file inside the Jar file found using **find** command.

I am using following command to check contents of Manifest file.

```
java -jar $(find . -type f -name "myjar-*" -print | head -n 1) -ai
```

It gives output on console -

```
Version: 2   
Name: MyName   
Company: ABC
```

Now, since on console i can see the contents of the file, how can I search whether "Na" exists for line which contains "Name" ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do. Specifically, what you think the `find` command is doing. It will just print the 1st file name found that begins with `myjar-`, is that what you want? You seem to want to parse the manifest file somehow but you don't tell us what you want to achieve.

Comment: Done. Does it make sense now ?

Comment: Thanks, better but still not clear. What is your desired output from the `find` and `head` commands? You seem to think that they will return `MyName`. Is that correct? You need to explain exactly what you are attempting. You say that you're using bash "to do that" but what is _that_?

Comment: Could you take a look now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are saying that this command:

```
java -jar $(find . -type f -name "myjar-*" -print | head -n 1) -ai
```

Returns this output:

```
Version: 2   
Name: MyName   
Company: ABC
```

And you want to check whether that output contains a line that starts with `Name:` and contains the string `Na` (excluding the `Na` in `Name:`). If so, you could do:

```
java -jar $(find . -type f -name "myjar-*" -print | head -n 1) -ai |
     | grep -q '^Name:.*Na' && echo YES
```

The `-q` flag tells `grep` not to print its matches. It simply returns a `0` exit code if a match was found. Therefore, you can use `&& command` to run a command if the match was successful. Here, I am running `echo YES` but you can change that to whatever command you want to run.